# Winforms two-way data binding won't update UI properly unless doing some other UI operations

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I'm debugging an old winform that uses two-way data binding under VS2017.

As for two-way binding, I used the following code:

```
var bs = new BindingSource(components) {DataSource = model};                    
_destinationComboBox.DataSource = model.GetDestination();
            _destinationComboBox.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("SelectedItem",
                                                              bs.DataSource,
                                                              "Destination", true,
                                                              DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));
```

The model has properly implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged`.Everything is good, but the GUI only updates after properties changed when I, for instance, switching tabs or click some buttons(perform some other UI operations).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is very confusing and hard to debug.

I finally found out that the VS2017(at least under 15.9.11) debugger has something to do with this. After detaching the debugger, the GUI updates once properties change, just as expected.